# How does Spring get the result from an endpoint that returns CompletableFuture object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-8, completable-future

In the code below, when the endpoint `getPerson` gets hit, the response will be a JSON of type Person. 
How does Spring convert `CompletableFuture<Person>` to `Person`?

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;


    @GetMapping("/persons/{personId}" )
    public CompletableFuture<Person> getPerson(@PathVariable("personId") Integer personId) {

        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> personService.getPerson(personId));
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to check the source, but presumably it does a `thenApply` to retrieve the eventual result and send it back to the client.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When the `CompletableFuture` is returned , it triggers Servlet 3.0 asynchronous processing feature which the execution of the `CompletableFuture` will be executed in other thread such that the server thread that handle the HTTP request can be free up as quickly as possible to process other HTTP requests. (See a series of blogpost start from [this](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/07/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support) for detailed idea)

The `@ResponseBody` annotated on the `@RestController` will cause Spring to convert the controller method 's retuned value (i.e `Person`) through a [HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestbody) registered internally. One of its implementation is [MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#rest-message-conversion) which will further delegate to the Jackson to serialise the `Person` object to a JSON string and send it back to the HTTP client by writing it to `HttpServletResponse`

Comment: How is Person java object  extracted from CompletableFutere<Person> under the hood? Is that happening by calling join method?

Comment: No . It will be adapted to the Spring 's `DeferredResult` . But from the `CompletableFutere` point of view , it just setup the processing pipeline by using `CompletableFutere.handle()` which will populated the `Person` to `DeferredResult`

Comment: Is there any way I can access the code that spring uses inside handle method? I'm looking for the way that spring handles the exceptions inside handle method. Does it wrap it into `CompletionException` or just throw the exception as is? The reason I'm asking is because I'm seeing two different behaviors for two different spring applications with different java versions.  @Ken

Comment: Do you mean you want to use your own code to handle the exception thrown from the `CompletableFutere`? If yes, you can checkout implementing a `DeferredResultProcessingInterceptor` 's `handleError()` method

Comment: I mean I want to see the implementation code that is passed to handle method that spring uses to get Person object from `CompletableFuture` @Ken

Comment: Just an additional question: Is it sufficient to leave out the `Async` Annotation on the controller? Usually you decorate async methods with `Async`.