# How to get data from a REST API endpoint that returns CompletableFuture

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http, completable-future

Folks,

My http endpoint returns CompletableFuture

```
@HttpEndpoint
public CompletableFuture<Student> processStudent(Request request){
       return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->saveStudent(request));
}
```

My http client is

```
 studentCompletableFuture = restTemplate.postForObject(URL, request, CompletableFuture.class);
 Student student = studentCompletableFuture .get();
```

I am not able to get student back to the client .

I searched in google and stackoverflow and found that once we get CompletableFuture with placeholder (empty response) as response from server, http connection will be closed and we cannot apply get() to get the student data.

My rest endpoint should be async, **how to get the actual student response back to client** ?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think `RestTemplate` was for synchronous calls only. You should use the newer `WebClient`.

Comment: go for spring reactive https://spring.io/reactive

Comment: A bit late but I think this might be helpful as it explains how Spring deals with endpoints returning completablefuture. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58505549/how-does-spring-get-the-result-from-an-endpoint-that-returns-completablefuture-o